# Is there a name and context where function for permutation defined as f(k) = #σ({1,2,…,k})∩{1,2,…,k} appeared ? (Measure of locality)

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

**Context:** Thinking on some machine learning questions on comparing the feature importances produced by different  methods - the following measure of concordance between two ordered lists seems to be useful. I am interested what is known about it ?

**Definition:** For given permutation σ on $N$ symbols let us define function for any integer $ 0 \le k \le N $ to be
$$ f(k) =  | σ({1,2,…,k})∩ \{ 1,2,…,k \} | $$ i.e. cardinality of the intersection between  $1...k$ and permutation applied to that set.

**Comment:** So it measures how far the original list $1...N$ is from the permutated list $σ(1)...σ(N)$.
More precisely, the function captures the locality of the permutation - that means if $ |σ(i)-i| $ is not big for all $i$ - the function would be linear: $f(k) ≈ k $ . While for generic permutation it would be given by parabola $k^2/N$ - the proof by David Pechersky can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/437545/10446 (See also generalization for several permutations: https://mathoverflow.net/a/438169/10446 )

**Question 1:** Would you be so kind to suggest some references on that function or related topics ?

**Question 2:** Similar question about the related function:
$ f_∪(k) =  | σ({1,2,…,k}) ∪ \{ 1,2,…,k \} | $ (union, not intersection), and their generalizations to several permutations.

PS

Some Python notebooks with analysis of the feature importances can be found in links here:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/curve-defined-by-permutations